# Python KIVY: delete a tab

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to delete a tab on a button press, using TabbedPanel widget.
I have two tabs on my pannel, and I want to delete the second one so that the pannel has only one tab.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'first tab'
        Label:
            text: 'First tab content area'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab2'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Second tab content area'
            Button:
                text: 'Button that deletes tab 2'
                background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)

""")


class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use `remove_widget()` by passing it `TabbedPanelItem`, but for this we can search through the text, but before that we switch to another tab.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'first tab'
        Label:
            text: 'First tab content area'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab2'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Second tab content area'
            Button:
                text: 'Button that deletes tab 2'
                background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)
                on_press: root.removeTab('tab2')

""")


class Test(TabbedPanel):
    def removeTab(self, name):
        tab = None
        for i in self.tab_list:
            if i.text == name:
                tab = i
                break
        if tab:
            self.switch_to(self.default_tab)
            self.remove_widget(tab)


class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you. How to make tab 1 selected and its content displayed, after deleting tab 2 ? Generically, I want when we delete  the tab x, it directly displays the content of the tab x-1 without having to click on it.

Comment: @MikeDelta You must be specific in your requirements, I will update it later. What if you delete the first tab that should be displayed?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I want the same behavior as the tabs of a browser like Firefox. It always display the x+1 tab when we delete a tab, except when we delete the last one, in that case it displays the x-1 tab.

Comment: I still can not find a solution, can you help me please? thank you